# Cats - how to use for-comprehension when `Monad` instance in scope?

Tags: scala, scala-cats, for-comprehension

How can I use for-comprehension on type `M` in the method below?

```
def foo[M[_]: Monad](m1: M[Int], m2: M[Int]) =
  for {
     a <- m1
     b <- m2
  } yield (a + b)
```

I'll get a

```
value flatMap is not a member of type parameter M[Int]
```

I can make it work by defining the `flatMap` and `map` methods like so:

```
implicit class MOps[A](m: M[A])(implicit monad: Monad[M]) {
  def flatMap[B](f: A => M[B]): M[B] = monad.flatMap(m)(f)
  def map[B](f: A => B): M[B]        = monad.map(m)(f)
}
```

But surely there must be a way for Cats to provide these methods?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try:

```
import cats.syntax.functor._, cats.syntax.flatMap._
```

Comment: Thanks. I was importing `cats.implicits._`, but I must have messed something up before when it was failing. It's working now. Thanks!